# how to start playing gta 5 online in xbox 360

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-network

I can't play GTA 5 online.  Whenever I try to connect online it tells
me your profile doesn't have the correct permission to connect online.  Can anyone please help me?  I have a Xbox 360 with Xbox Live Silver

Comment: Xbox Live Silver does NOT allow you to play games online. You have to buy an Xbox Live Gold membership.

Answer (score 7):

You need Xbox Live Gold to play games online.  If you want to play online, you must pay for Gold.

Answer (score -2):

that is a lie i was just playin gta 5 online with my freind now your trying ot rip off people i play gta5 online for free i just have to have to go to setting click on wifi and then click xbox live connection then go to your profile then click xbox live it is ganna say if you wanna makea acconut for xbox live make one